# best way to preprocess the data

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I have data which has following schema

`person_id | category_id | date | type`

Each day data collected is huge close to 95GB on average.
My use-case is to fetch all the person_ids for given category_id in provided date range.
This is present on hdfs in csv files.
When using spark to process for 3 weeks it takes half an hour to run on actual dump.
How do I preprocess it to increase performance of my spark job ?
I tried grouping on date but did not help much.

Comment: did you can change the input file format? by the way you can write the csv on hdfs partitioned by year/month/day/category_id/csvfilehere

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following to start with (as we don't have specifics about your data or cluster. Share your Spark Web UI screenshots)

- Preprocess data and save it in efficient binary formats like Parquet (or Avro)
- Partition by `date` or `person_id`
- See if there are straggler tasks (Data skew)
- Use efficient serialization formats (Kryo) and compress to reduce shuffle sizes if shuffling is what is consuming lot of processing time